# Glassfish admin console faile

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, application-server

I use glassfish 3.0.1 on windows 2003 with JDK 6u24.
When I start the server and try to login to the admin console (4848) I will receive this error message:

```
[#|2011-02-24T12:59:37.578+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-48
48-(2);|Cannot refresh Catalog : Connection timed out: connect|#]
```

**Update**

```
[#|2011-02-24T12:58:51.343+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|null|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadNam
e=Thread-23;|The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:51.343+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|null|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadNam
e=Thread-23;|The Admin Console is loading...|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:52.296+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Created HTT
P listener http-listener-1 on port 80|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:52.296+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Created HTT
P listener http-listener-2 on port 8181|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:52.296+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Created HTT
P listener admin-listener on port 4848|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:52.343+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Created vir
tual server server|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:52.343+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Created vir
tual server __asadmin|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:53.531+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Virtual ser
ver server loaded system default web module|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:54.671+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|SEC100
2: Security Manager is OFF.|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:54.937+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Securi
ty startup service called|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:54.953+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|SEC114
3: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.|#
]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:55.062+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread
-23;|Realm admin-realm of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.
FileRealm successfully created.|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:55.062+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread
-23;|Realm file of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRea
lm successfully created.|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:55.062+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread
-23;|Realm certificate of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certi
ficate.CertificateRealm successfully created.|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:55.078+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core
.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Securi
ty service(s) started successfully....|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:56.687+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.resource.we
bcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Initializing Mojarra 2
.0.2 (FCS b10) for context ''|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:58.546+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-23;|Loading app
lication __admingui at /|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:58.546+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|null|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadNam
e=Thread-23;|Loading __admingui Application done is 7203 ms|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:58:58.546+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|null|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadNam
e=Thread-23;|The Admin Console application is loaded.|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:59:02.515+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.tool
s.admin.org.glassfish.server|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-4848-(2);
|AMX ComplianceMonitor: ValidationLevel = full, UnregisterNonCompliant = false,
LogInaccessibleAttributes = true|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:59:02.828+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.tool
s.admin.org.glassfish.server|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-24;|AMX config read
, domain config registered as amx:pp=/,type=domain|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:59:03.046+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.tool
s.admin.org.glassfish.server|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=Thread-27;|J2EEDomain regi
stered at amx:pp=/,type=J2EEDomain,j2eeType=J2EEDomain,name=amx|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:59:03.046+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.tool
s.admin.org.glassfish.server|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-4848-(2);
|AMXStartupServiceNew: AMX ready for use, DomainRoot = amx:pp=,type=domain-root|
#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:59:10.843+0330|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.c
ontainer.web.com.sun.web.security|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-4848
-(2);|Web login failed: Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:
Failed file login for admin.|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:59:10.843+0330|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|org.apache.catalina.conne
ctor.Request|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-4848-(2);|PWC4011: Unable
 to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request param
eters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been cal
led|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:59:16.093+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_Thre
adID=25;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-4848-(2);|admin console: initSessionAttribu
tes()|#]

[#|2011-02-24T12:59:37.578+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-48
48-(2);|Cannot refresh Catalog : Connection timed out: connect|#]

[#|2011-02-24T13:08:09.015+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_Thre
adID=28;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-4848-(1);|admin console: initSessionAttribu
tes()|#]

[#|2011-02-24T13:08:30.125+0330|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-48
48-(1);|Cannot refresh Catalog : Connection timed out: connect|#]

[#|2011-02-24T13:14:16.546+0330|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.Gr
izzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-13;|Interrupting idle Threa
d: http-thread-pool-4848-(2)|#]
```

Comment: can you please put some more stacktrace

Comment: sure, I will update the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Glassfish has a lot of trouble recently caused by the new version 3.1. The admin console tries to look for new updates at start-up. If the update server will not respond in a certain time, the update count fails or take a long time.

You could first try to choose a different update server with glassfishs update tool. You will find it in `glassfish/bin` folder.

If this doesn't work, you could disable the update module of the glassfish admin console by renaming the file `console-updatecenter-plugin.jar` in the folder `glassfish/glassfish/modules`.

You could also disable network access from the admin console by adding the following to the JVM-Options of your domain.xml:

> -Dcom.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.NO_NETWORK=true